# Update UILabel frame inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to update the frame of uilabel containing the todo title so that it would be centered vertically when there is no todo description.

Here is `cellForRowAt indexPath`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! customCell

    // Configure the cell...

    let todo = todos[indexPath.row]

    cell.setup(todo: todo.title, todoDescription : todo.todoDescription)

    return cell
}
```

and in the custom cell class:

```
import UIKit

class customCell: UITableViewCell {

let titleLabel: UILabel! = UILabel(...) //cenvenience initializer setting the uilabel frame
let descriptionLabel: UILabel! = UILabel(...)

func setup(todo : String, todoDescription : String?) {

    titleLabel.text = todo

    if let todo_descr = todoDescription {
        descriptionLabel.text = todo_descr
    } else {
        descriptionLabel.text = ""
        titleLabel.frame = ... //update the frame of the todo title to be centered vertically in the cell, basically change the y of the frame
    }

}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    titleLabel.frame = ... //initial frame, which is not centered vertically
    descriptionLabel.frame = ...

    contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

when I print the `titleLabel` frame, it prints the desired frame properties. But in the simulator, the frame is still the one given to the label in `layoutSubviews`.

I've tried `self.layoutIfNeeded()` in the `setup` function but it's not working. How can I update the cell subviews given the presence or lack of the todo description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way is very code less, design your `UITableViewCell` as below with `Auto Layout Constraints`

[image: UItableViewCell Design]

1. Todo title will be the static height
2. Set number of lines for Todo description to 0, in properties. So when there is no description Todo description will automatically reduce its height to Zero. Because we are adding the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in height calculation methods

And then add these two datasource methods in view controller

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath you call

```
cell.setup(todo: todo.title, todoDescription : todo.todoDescription)
```

In this method you set frame of titleLabel center vertically, and all works.
But after that cell calls method layoutSubviews(), and in this method you set frame of labels initial, not depending on description text.

```
titleLabel.frame = ... //initial frame, which is not centered vertically
descriptionLabel.frame = ...
```

And all labels, sets on their initial frames.
The problem is that layoutSubviews() method calls after setup() method.
So no need to set the frame of labels in layoutSubviews method. They already have a right frames setting in label initializer or setup() method.